# Captcha missing

Tags: forms

I installed captcha module in Drupal 7 and works with all forms except Contact form. This is the main one I would like it to work with. I am new to this and it's my first try with Drupal, I have one site running Zencart properly and now would like a blog site.             Drupal site as it is now    " http://jamair.x10.mx/drupal/ "

Comment: I think that a screenshot of your settings would be a bit more useful than the link to your site.

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled it for that form?

Go to yoursite/admin/config/people/captcha and check to make sure the captcha is enabled on the site contact form. It looks like it's functioning fine on that site (as it's showing up ok on the login block) so my first guess would be it's just not turned on for that form.